# What are the good and free alternative to Helvetica when use as web font?

Tags: fonts, typography, web-fonts, web-safe

Sans-serif typeface is usually in web, so what are the free/open/cross-platform choices that can replace Helvetica?

**By replacing Helvetica I mean are there any font which is better than Helvetica for web? The reason I ask is I have read an [article](http://www.64notes.com/design/stop-helvetica-arial/) demoing Helvetica is often not the best choice for web.**

So probably two options are needed:

- For heading
- For paragraph

Comment: This may answer your question: [free 'Helvetica Neue' alternative](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/15464/8708)

Comment: @JohnB, I have updated my question, I am not finding a replacement due to the price, but I am looking for any free alternative which is better than Helvetica. You can find some screenshot in my above link for comparsion. Thanks.

Comment: "Better" + "Free" is sometimes doable, but rarely are you going to get both features in one.

Answer (score 4):

The good one is [Neue Haas Grotesk](http://www.fontbureau.com/nhg/), but if you need a typeface only for headings I can propose my own typeface :) Take a look on [this image](http://behance.vo.llnwd.net/profiles18/1080627/projects/8080281/8c508fd6968215274c5279620ec2c040.png).

[image]

Comment: Beautiful font, but it's not free in any way at all

Answer (score 2):

The most common/closest 'alternative' to Helvetica is likely Arial, which is already installed on most computers, so you don't even need to use it as a web font.

Comment: Take the quiz! http://www.ironicsans.com/helvarialquiz/

Comment: @horatio so far I'm 100% but paused to say "National Car & Truck" is not either one. I guessed correctly on that one but its not right. Its all about knowing that Helvetica uses horizontal lines where arial is sloped.

Comment: If you want a Google web font, the closest match to Helvetica Neue (closer than Arial) is Arimo. For a font stack that puts the most Helvetica-like fonts first, includes Arimo, and suppresses the substitution of Arial for Helvetica on Windows systems, see http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/9054 .

Answer (score 1):

Re-posting as answer here just in case someone misses the comment.

I've always used [Liberation Sans](http://www.dafont.com/liberation-sans.font) for web, because it's one of the fonts that render the best with `@font-face`:

[image]