# Faux Bold in Indesign creates thin outline on certain characters

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts

I've added .25 stroke faux bolding to my text in indesign:

[image: indesign document screencap - there is an unwanted extra outline of an "e" in the text]

If you look closely... theres this thin outline around the "e"s in "Tech Workforce". If I zoom in far enough on the indesign doc, it disappears! But unfortunately, when I export the PDF for print (the intended purpose), the issue persists:

[image: 'e' with an undesirable thin outline]

I would like to remove this outline. Either methods for removing the outline or for redoing the text so that it doesn't create the outline would be much appreciated !

Comment: My first instinct was a rendering glitch, but if it's in the pdf and looking at the last image, that is quite the offset. What if you make a new document and try the same thing? Just to kinda see if it's something you've done in that document.

Answer (score 1):

I would just work clean, remove the outlines and either use Bold or Black. The difference in Bold vs. outlined Bold may just be irrelevant to many of your readers.

Then, the pink numbers you are showing kind of look pretty close to Helvetica Black. Why over complicate it? Working with a timeless typeface and put feathers on its head? :) Neahh..

Or just use another font in the thickness you need, there are many [alternatives to Helvetica](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/602/visually-similar-alternatives-to-helvetica).

Comment: Helvetica Black is exactly what I needed, thank you!!